# How to link a SQlite Extension Source File into Xcode for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

I use a statically linked library for Sqlite in an iPhone Xcode project. I am now trying to include a .C extension to Sqlite in this project. However, I am having trouble making the Sqlite in the build SEE the extension.

The statically linked Sqlite library works fine. Also the .C extension works on my desktop, and builds fine as a statically linked library in Xcode. However, the custom functions it defines are missing when called.

For example, I load the extension as so with no errors.

```
SELECT load_extension('extension_name.so');
```

But when I try to call a function defined in the extension, I get this message

```
DB Error: 1 "no such function: custom_function"
```

Does anyone know much about linking a Sqlite extension into an Xcode project?

Comment: I'm also facing the same kind of issue, did you find any solution about this ? (I'm trying to get spatialite runing onto the iPhone and it's abstracts itself as a SQLite extension .... :/)

Comment: yonel, you should check out this ... http://groups.google.com/group/spatialite-users/browse_thread/thread/5e6b035dbf3d1b91

It seems people have got spatialite already running, however I could not get my extension running based on this post. You may have more luck!

Comment: :) This is my post :) I manage to compile it, but this installation looks more complex. However, while digging into spatialite, I may have an answer for your issue. I'm posting it as an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said by @jbworld you cannot load dynamic libraries on the iPhone, so this link should be made statically, at compilation time. While reading at the code of spatialite (that's an SQLite extension), I found that kind of invocation:

```
void spatialite_init (int verbose) {
/* used when SQLite initializes SpatiaLite via statically linked lib */
    sqlite3_auto_extension ((void (*)(void)) init_static_spatialite);
}
```

And the `init_static_spatialite` code:

```
static void init_static_spatialite (sqlite3 * db, char **pzErrMsg,
            const sqlite3_api_routines * pApi)
{
    SQLITE_EXTENSION_INIT2 (pApi);
/* setting the POSIX locale for numeric */
    setlocale (LC_NUMERIC, "POSIX");
    *pzErrMsg = NULL;
    sqlite3_create_function (db, "spatialite_version", 0, SQLITE_ANY, 0,
                             fnct_spatialite_version, 0, 0);
    sqlite3_create_function (db, "proj4_version", 0, SQLITE_ANY, 0,
                             fnct_proj4_version, 0, 0);
    sqlite3_create_function (db, "geos_version", 0, SQLITE_ANY, 0,
                             fnct_geos_version, 0, 0);
    sqlite3_create_function (db, "GeometryConstraints", 3, SQLITE_ANY, 0,
                             fnct_GeometryConstraints, 0, 0);
    sqlite3_create_function (db, "CheckSpatialMetaData", 0, SQLITE_ANY, 0,
                             fnct_CheckSpatialMetaData, 0, 0);
...
```

So it looks like if the `sqlite_auto_extension` enables you to statically link an extension. [The documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/auto_extension.html) seems to confirm that:

> “This API can be invoked at program startup in order to register one or more statically linked extensions that will be available to all new database connections.”

Then, at runtime, for spatialite, I just have to invoke the `spatialite_init(0)` to get the extension up and running.

### Invoke such method *before* loading any sqlite DB.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yonel - I'll have to look into this in a couple of days. I voted you up for persistence and helpfulness. Promise you a tick too when I can verify. Cheers!

Comment: @crunchyt Did you manage to get this working? I'm in the same situation and could use some advice..

Comment: @StuR: Not so really. I could get a module to build into it, but not a custom extension.

Comment: Hi. I'm having a similar issue with SpatiaLite: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518158/error-no-such-function-x-error-no-such-function-geomfromtext

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for you to build your custom functions directly into your main executable, and tell sqlite about them with [sqlite3_create_function](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/c3ref/create_function.html)?

I don't know what details apply in this situation, but I do recall that the iPhone is funny about loading code at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The function load_extension loads a shared library (.so). This is not allowed on the iPhone. You will have to recompile your static library to include the extension you wish to use.

Comment: This sounds about right. I have tried adding my extension as a static library via New Target. However I it did not seem to be visible to the custom version of SQlite I included.

Any suggestions or hints you can think of? Thanks heaps!