# Xcode SQLite Extension for use on iPhone

Tags: xcode, sqlite

I am looking to use a SQLite extension in my application, with the exception of SpatiaLite I cannot find any other examples of where extensions are being used. The following post had some suggestions but nothing that made me any wiser: [How to link a SQlite Extension Source File into Xcode for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303140/how-to-link-a-sqlite-extension-source-file-into-xcode-for-iphone)

The extension that I am trying to load is: https://github.com/mateusza/SQLite-Levenshtein/blob/master/src/levenshtein.c

I have compiled the above extension but of course I cannot include this in my application for usage like:

```
SELECT load_extension('extension.sqlext');
```

Can somebody tell me how to either:

1) Compile sqlite to include my extension.

2) Use sqlite_auto_extension to include my extension.

Edit: I have sqlite amalgamation and the above source files now included in my project, I just need an example of how to use sqlite_auto_extension for use with the above extension, and where to call this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it seems you cannot use dynamic libraries for iOS project.
However, in your particular case you can get sources of that module, add them to project (there is one file only), and change some code in: int sqlite3_extension_init()
to call only sqlite3_create_function(db, "levenshtein", 2, SQLITE_ANY, 0, levenFunc, 0, 0);
And do that call after opening your database.

Comment: I thought that I couldn't use a pre compiled binary into my project? Also I get this: 2011-06-08 18:20:10.434 SQL[2841:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while creating detail view statement. 'no such function: load_extension'' ...which would probably mean that I may have to compile sqlite with the load_extension function anyway

Comment: You can always grab a source file from SQLite site (it is called sqlite amalgamation, if memory serves, where all the stuff is placed into one file), instead of using one from iOS SDK. And, why not to have compiled library in your project folder? It should be okay.

Comment: Yes I've tried that, I'm now using the sqlite amalgamation. Although I'm now not getting a error this isn't working:     NSString *levenshtein = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"levenshtein.sqlext"];

    const char *sql = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select load_extension('%@'); select * from tablename",levenshtein] UTF8String];

- When I compile the extension I'm using: gcc -m32 -bundle -fPIC -Isqlite3 -o levenshtein.sqlext levenshtein.c 

Is this the correct architecture for the iPhone?

Comment: Hm. It seems I was wrong with my assumption. Please see completely rewritten answer.

Comment: Still can't my head around this, I've got it to a point where I have the sqlite amalgamation loaded, my levenshtein.c file included. Now I need to call sqlite3_auto_extension from somewhere - I don't know what file to do this in - my app delegate? and which files I need to import.

Comment: No, you don't need to call sqlite32_auto_extension, you need to call rewritten  sqlite3_extension_init() from levenstein.c, after you opened your database.

Comment: I've made progress and did as you say, it now calls the function which in turn calls the 'levenFunc' function. I am now having EXC_BAD_ACCESS on sqlite3_value_type or sqlite3_value_text from within that function, screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/Zx4fq.png Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind I got it working, I had to define sqlite3_api_routines. Thanks for your help, I got there eventually.